# Meteor Triangulation

Tags: solar-system, meteor

I´m looking for literature and examples on the subject of meteor triangulation. For example, graphical representation and calculation of a meteor orbit observed from two different geographical positions.

Best regards

Comment: There's an enormous amount of material available, just search for "meteor trajectory".